# Awk variable as regex

Tags: awk

```bash
awk -F "," -v groups=$groups '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){if (groups ~ $i) print}}' test.txt
```

I want to iterate over file and if variable `groups` contains word from i's column in line print this line, but the code doesn't seem to work.

```
$ cat test.txt
project1/1.txt,2023-03-19_17-40-49,foo
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar

$ groups="bar,baz"
```

Expected Output:

```
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
```

Comment: Your awk command is wrong

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mre].  Include sample input file and regex string and expected outputs.

Comment: please update the question to show the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: Actual output is none. Nothing is printed.

Comment: that's odd ... in my system your code generates 3 lines of output; even if I convert `test.txt` to include windows/dos line endings (`\r\n`) I still get one line of output

Comment: I get the same output as markp-fuso using GNU Awk 5.0.1. What version are you using? I'm not an expert, but I seem to remember Mac Awk works differently, so that might be it. You can check with `awk --version`.

Comment: @MwahMallah Please mention that in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running OP's current code I get the following output:

```
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
```

If the objective is to only print a line once, even if it has more than one match (eg, the 3rd line of the input file), then one simple modification is to skip to the `next` line of input after the first `print`, eg:

```
awk -F "," -v groups=$groups '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){if (groups ~ $i) {print;next}}}' test.txt
                                                                   ^     ^^^^^^
```

This generates:

```
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
groups="bar|baz"   # Note | for alternate.

awk -F, -v groups="$groups" '
{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){if (groups ~ $i) print}}' file
```

Prints:

```
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
```

But you *may* want instead is:

```
awk -F, -v groups="$groups" '$0~groups' file
```

Prints:

```
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
```

Answer (score 1):

If your real data is like your example then your code would run faster and be more robust if you used a hash lookup for full-field literal string comparisons rather than partial regexp matching, e.g.:

```
$ awk -F',' -v grps='bar,baz' '
    BEGIN { split(grps,tmp); for (i in tmp) groups[tmp[i]] }
    { for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in groups) { print; next} }
' test.txt
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
```

For example, try this alternative input:

```
$ cat test.txt
project1/1.txt,2023-03-19_17-40-49,foo
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,foobar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,b.r
```

with these groups:

```
$ awk -F',' -v grps='bar' 'BEGIN{split(grps,tmp); for (i in tmp) groups[tmp[i]]} {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in groups) { print; next} }' test.txt
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_17-41-06,bar
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,baz,bar
```

```
$ awk -F',' -v grps='b.r' 'BEGIN{split(grps,tmp); for (i in tmp) groups[tmp[i]]} {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in groups) { print; next} }' test.txt
project1/4.txt,2023-03-19_18-04-23,b.r
```

and note that the above full-field literal string search for `bar` does not output the `foobar` line, unlike if you were doing a partial match, and a search for `b.r` does not output lines containing `bar`, unlike if you were doing a regexp comparison.